# HTML - How to left align keeping at the center of table?

Tags: html, css

This is my first real experience with HTML. I'm aiming to reproduce a result like this:

[image]

To do that I creating inside a table. I'm at the start of the code development, but this was I got so far:

```
<body>
<table id="container" style="width: 98%;">
  <table id="header" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      TODO
    </td>
  </table>
  <table id="content" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <td valign="top" style="text-align: center">
      <h2 align="center" style="line-height: 40%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Beginner's Guide to Web Development</h2>
      <p align="center" style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Curious about web development but not sure where to start?</p>
      <p align="center" style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Or maybe you just need to brush up on some of the basics.</p>
      <p align="center" style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Our new Beginner's Guide to Web Development has you</p>
      <p align="center" style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">covered! Read through it now to explore (or rediscover) the</p>
      <p align="center" style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">foundations of web dev.</p>
    </td>
  </table>
  <table id="footer" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <td valign="top" align="center">
      TODO
    </td>
  </table>
</table>
```

And the result is:

[image: enter image description here[2]

So, How could align the text to following that red line but without descentralizing?

[image]

**OBS:** I know that is a bad practice to use the `style` tag, but the purpose is to develop a code that can be read in any email application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table id="container" style="width: 98%;">
   <table id="header" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
      <td valign="top" align="center">
         TODO
      </td>
   </table>
   <table id="content" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center">
         <div style="
            width: 76%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: left;
            ">
            <h2 style="line-height: 40%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Beginner's Guide to Web Development</h2>
            <p style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Curious about web development but not sure where to start?</p>
            <p style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Or maybe you just need to brush up on some of the basics.</p>
            <p style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">Our new Beginner's Guide to Web Development has you</p>
            <p style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">covered! Read through it now to explore (or rediscover) the</p>
            <p style="line-height: 35%; font-family: 'Roboto';">foundations of web dev.</p>
         </div>
      </td>
   </table>
   <table id="footer" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
      <td valign="top" align="center">
         TODO
      </td>
   </table>
</table>
```